# Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, asp.net

i try to submit documents through dropdownlist 
when admin select approve/reject in gridview once then click on submit  button then action performed 
i code in submit button

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //foreach (GridViewRow row in GrdFileApprove.Rows)
        //{
        //    //If row in Datarow then go ahead and find the control
        //    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        //    {
        //        DropDownList DropDownListcontrol = row.FindControl("DropDownList4") as DropDownList;


        //    }
        //}
        string connStr 
       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mydms"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection mySQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            mySQLconnection.Open();
        }

        // Sql Command Object  
        //SqlCommand mySqlCommand;


        DropDownList drdList;
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GrdFileApprove.Rows)
        {
            drdList = (DropDownList)
        (GrdFileApprove.Rows[row.RowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList4"));
            if (GrdFileApprove.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["ApproveID"].ToString() != 
      drdList.SelectedValue)  
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("approved", mySQLconnection);
    }  
}  

if (mySQLconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)  
{  
    mySQLconnection.Close();  
}
```

it show me error in this line

```
if (GrdFileApprove.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["ApproveID"].ToString() != 
      drdList.SelectedValue)
```

ERROR

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index

ANY SOLUTION?

Comment: `Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

Comment: Clearly you're trying to index a collection element which doesn't exist.  Does `row.RowIndex` exist in `DataKeys`?  If so, does `"ApproveID"` exist in `DataKeys[row.RowIndex]`?  One of them doesn't, and you can debug to find out which one.

Comment: Just for fun.  What is GrdFileApprove defined as?  (What is it's type?)

Comment: @ebyrob From context, it would appear to be a `GridView`.

Comment: @Servy Yes, I just thought it might be nice to be sure...

Comment: I seem to recall a "special" GridView table row which wouldn't have a positive RowIndex necessarily.  (Hitting the header perhaps?)

Answer (score -1):

Look at your

```
GrdFileApprove.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["ApproveID"]
```

I'd put a breakpoint in this line and check your GrdFileApprove.DataKeys and see if your row.RowIndex value and "ApproveID" is valid to access with the DataKeys collection.

Comment: That's not the line throwing an exception though; it's the following line.

Comment: Which line was it throwing?

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis He states that in the question.